# Increase or decrease parent div height based on the changes in the children element

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/9b90twgf/15/

```js
 $("#add").on("click",function(){
var top = parseInt($("#parentDiv .childDiv:last").css("top").split("px")[0])+90;

$("#parentDiv").append("<div class='childDiv' style='position:absolute; top:"+top+"px;'>divvvvvv</div>");
});

 $("#remove").on("click",function(){
$("#parentDiv .childDiv:last").remove();
});
```

```css
  #parentDiv
     {
      background: antiquewhite;
      }
     .childDiv
     {
     background: yellow;
      width: 700px; 
      height: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add</button><button id="remove">remove</button>
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 210px;" id="parentDiv">
      <div class="childDiv" style="position: absolute;">
    Div one
    </div>

    <div class="childDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 75px;">
    div two
   </div>
   <div class="childDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 140px;">
   div three
  </div>
  </div>
```

I have one parent div, under this I will append and remove HTML elements as children, if I remove children element parent div have to shrink its height automatically and if I add it have to expand automatically, my requirement is both parent and children must have position absolute(style="position:absolute")

Comment: add position:relative to parent and give a try

Comment: no it should be position: absolute, for my other requirements

Comment: Absolute position on child divs mean they are not factored in the width and height of the parent container. If it's necessary to have these as absolute, you will need to explicitly set the width and height of the parent based on some calculation of the combined child height and widths.

Comment: mr @bhv what are you trying to say?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9b90twgf/16/ - make sure to amend the final height to match your hard-coded top value of 90

Comment: Would it be an option to use CSS flex-box positioning for the child divs inside of the absolute positioned parent instead of positioning the children absolutely?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rugrqjse/1/)

Comment: Isn't it how css works basicly? if you don't set a fixed height it should expand or decrease when adding elements.

Comment: @user5014677 Sure if width and height are 'auto' and children are positioned relative to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  addChild();
  calculateParentHeight();
});

$("#remove").on("click", function() {
  $(".parent .child:last").remove();
  calculateParentHeight();
});

function calculateParentHeight() {
  var height = 0;
  
  $('.parent .child').each(function() {
    height = height + $(this).height();  
  });

  $('.parent').css('height', height + 20 + 'px');
}

calculateParentHeight();

function addChild() {
  var top = 0;
  
  $('.parent .child').each(function() {
    top = top + $(this).height();  
  });

  $(".parent").append("<div class='child' style='top:" + top + "px;'>divvvvvv</div>");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  background: antiquewhite;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="remove">remove</button>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="position: absolute;">
    Div one
  </div>

  <div class="child" style="position: absolute; top: 50px;">
    div two
  </div>
  <div class="child" style="position: absolute; top: 100px;">
    div three
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Nick De Jaeger, I also thought about same solution, but it is possible to achieve this by CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

Change height of parent div on add and remove of children

```js
 $("#add").on("click",function(){
var top = parseInt($("#parentDiv .childDiv:last").css("top").split("px")[0])+90;

$("#parentDiv").append("<div class='childDiv' style='position:absolute; top:"+top+"px;'>divvvvvv</div>");
$("#parentDiv").css('height', top + 90);
});

 $("#remove").on("click",function(){
$("#parentDiv").css('height',$("#parentDiv .childDiv:last-child").css('top'));
$("#parentDiv .childDiv:last").remove();
});
```

```css
  #parentDiv
     {
      background: antiquewhite;
      }
     .childDiv
     {
     background: yellow;
      width: 700px; 
      height: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add</button><button id="remove">remove</button>
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 210px;" id="parentDiv">
      <div class="childDiv" style="position: absolute;">
    Div one
    </div>

    <div class="childDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 75px;">
    div two
   </div>
   <div class="childDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 140px;">
   div three
  </div>
  </div>
```